Image not showing using Reflex framework
I am trying to display an image using the python web framework Reflex, and the image is not showing, its just a question mark where the image is supposed to be.
I have my code just as the documentation has it.
rx.image(src="/favicon.ico"),
this is inside the index function

Hi, and welcome to the StackOverflow community. You need to provide more information for the contributors to work with. There are some good guidelines on the forum regarding how to post good questions. I suggest you spend some time reading them. At a high level, we need to know what steps you have already tried, where they failed, and preferably some code examples.

some servers serves static files only from special folder - like /static/favicon.ico - You should also check DevTools (tab Network) in Chrome/Firefox to see if browser had problem to get file from server

in question (not in comments) you could add link to documentation which you use. And you could create minimal working code so we could simply copy and test it.

I never used reflex but after creating project I see folder .web/public/ and often on servers folder public means folder for images, and other files which you use on page. Maybe image should be in this folder. .web/public/favicon.ico

After creating example project dashboard I see images in .web/public and assets
.web/public/favicon.ico
.web/public/logo.jpg

assets/favicon.ico
assets/logo.jpg

In documentation is function Search with button Ask AI and I got answer that you have to put image in assets
And I think

for rx.image(src="/favicon.ico") you need assets/favicon.ico
for rx.image(src="/other/image.jpg") you need assets/other/image.jpg


As I remember (classic) web servers usually used folder public for images, css, js and other files which can be send to browser directly, without processing code.
Maybe you have to put image (and other files) in assets and later when it generates working web page in .web then it can copy images to .web/public
